Topology: Torus and Quotient Spaces
just started with my first course in abstract mathematics, namely Point-Set Topology. Would appreciate some help here! ($I = [-1,1]$)
I have a very simple question on a Torus. Firstly, I have seen somewhere that a Torus is defined as $S^{1} \times S^{1}$ but then while learning quotient topology, I saw the Torus is defined as $I \times I/ ∼$ where the equivalence relation is $(−1, s) ∼ (1, s), (s, −1) ∼ (s, 1) , s ∈ I $. And we have that $ I \times I/ ∼$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1} \times S^{1}$.
So I am kind of getting lost in these concepts. Especially how a Torus is actually defined? For example, for a circle, its pretty straightforward, a circle $S^{1}$ is defined as $  = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$ and its homoemorphic to $[0,1]$ under a equivalence in which you identify end points.

As $-1 \notin I$, you need to fix something in the question.

These are equivalent definitions. The quotient definition is actually the more intuitive one. It can be (quiet easily) proved that the quotient space is homeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1$, which is by itself a very non intuitive definition. (note that it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$!)

@mathcounterexamples.net Yes, my bad. Thanks

Welcome to MSe.  Your questions will be better received if you state them clearly. In this post you ask "how a Torus is actually defined?", but you also answer it by giving a definition in your post. So what is it that you need help with?

@RandyMarsh Thank you. So I gave two potential definitions, and I am confused if they are the same or not?

They are homeomorphic, hence isomorphic in the category of topological spaces, so you should consider them the same topological space.

When topologists speak of the torus, they mean either

A closed surface homeomorphic to a product of circles $S^{1} \times S^{1}$; or less commonly
The equivalence class of all such topological spaces up to homeomorphism.

Let's look at the example you understand, modified slightly: The circle "is" $I = [-1, 1]$ with its endpoints identified. (More carefully, the circle is homeomorphic to the quotient of $I$ by the equivalence relation "$x \sim y$ if and only if $x = y$ or $\{x, y\} = \{-1, 1\}$.")
To prove $I/\sim$ is homeomorphic to the circle $\{(x, y) \in \mathbf{R}^{2} : x^{2} + y^{2} = 1\}$, it suffices to show the formula $\gamma(t) = (\cos\pi t, \sin\pi t)$ defines a continuous, bijective mapping $\gamma:I/\sim\ \to S^{1}$ whose inverse is continuous.
<>
If this makes sense in detail, the torus is just the Cartesian produst of this example with itself. We start with the square $I \times I$, and define an equivalence relation whose restriction to each horizontal slice and each vertical slice is $\sim$ on $I$. That is, we identify $(s, -1) \sim (s, 1)$ for all $s$ in $[-1, 1]$, and we identify $(-1, t) \sim (1, t)$ for all $t$ in $[-1, 1]$. (Literally we need scare quotes around "is," since these slices are not literally $I$, but "naturally identified copies" $\{s\} \times I$ and $I \times \{t\}$.) The result, perhaps unsurprisingly, "is" $S^{1} \times S^{1}$.
<>
You didn't ask, but differential and complex geometers should not speak of the torus. When we're considering extra structure on $S^{1} \times S^{1}$, that extra structure is typically far from unique. To specify your torus to a compex geometer, you have to say something like "The torus obtained by quotienting the complex plane by $2\mathbf{Z} + 2i\mathbf{Z}$."
To give a loose analogy, speaking of the torus in differential or complex geometry is like walking into an American fried toroidal pastry establishment and saying, "Give me the donut." Instead you have to ask for the donut with strawberry icing and sprinkles." Note also that you're happy with any representative of the equivalence class that gets handed to you, as in item 1. above.

These two definitions are equivalent, since you can show that the spaces are homeomorphic. To understand both definitions more intuitively: For $S^1\times S^1$, visualize it as drawing a circle, and for eacht point on that circle, drawing a circle perpendicular to the first circle. For the quotient space, glue both opposite ends of a square together. If you visualize it, the result should be a torus for both definitions.

A square has 4 "ends". What you meant is to glue the opposite ends without twisting.

So with this reasoning, I can even say S^{1} is equivalent to [0,1]/∼ ?

@user1325970 yes, it is, assuming you define ~ correctly.
